# How to add a hyperlink in an intents JSON file for a chat bot?

Tags: python, json, hyperlink, chatbot

I am coding a simple chat bot in python using keras, Tkinter and nltk. I have a json file of intents like so:

```
{"intents": [
   
    {"tag": "greeting",
          #This is what the user enters
         "patterns": ["Hi!", "Hello!"],
          #This is what the bot replies
         "responses": ["Hello to you too!", "Hi! Please view this link: www.examplelink.com"],
         "context": [""]
    }
]
}
```

The chat bot response includes the link as simple text, instead of it being a hyperlink. I have googled "JSON hyperlink code format" but, did not find an appropriate solution. Could someone please show me the correct way to encode the hyperlink? Or is it not possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working to display intents[0].responses on a `html` then try this:

```
"responses": ["Hello to you too!", "Hi! Please view this link: <a href='www.examplelink.com'>www.examplelink.com</a>"],
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was actually outputting the intents on to a Tkinter GUI from the JSON file without using html. I attempted the code and the <a href... portions were output as text along with the rest.